# If a theory has many mutually non-embeddable countable models can it have a countable $\omega$-saturated model?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

A theory can have $2^\omega$-many non-isomorphic countable models but has a countable $\omega$-saturated model. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305602/if-a-theory-has-a-countable-omega-saturated-model-does-it-need-to-have-only-c)

Can there be a countable $\omega$-saturated model if the theory has $2^\omega$-many non-isomorphic countable models which are mutually not embeddable into each other?

(The theory is assumed to be complete and countable.)

Comment: Probably you want to consider only complete theories?

Comment: The theory I gave as an example in the MSE question you linked to already has continuum-many mutually non-embeddable models!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Let $T$ be the theory of the model $\langle\mathbb{Q},<,c_i\rangle$, where we choose constants $c_i$ as follows: every natural number $n$ is the value of a constant, and for each $n$, we name the numbers occuring on a decreasing rational sequence in $[n,n+1)$ converging to $n$. For example, perhaps we have a constant for each $n$ and also for $n+1/2^k$ for $k\geq 1$. No other rationals are named except these.

This theory is complete, being the theory of the model. Note also that we inherit the QE result from endless dense linear orders, since any formula mentions only finitely many constants.

The models of this theory are determined by which cuts between (or above) the constants they fill. That is, for which $n$ does the model have something above $n$ but below every constant in the sequence coming down to $n$? And is there any point in the model on top of all the constants?

There is therefore a countable saturated model $M$, since we can simply fill all those cuts with a new copy of $\mathbb{Q}$. Every model of the theory embeds elementarily into this model by Cantor's back-and-forth argument, once one has mapped the constants across. So this model will realize all the necessary types.

But meanwhile, we have a countably infinite collection of 1-types that we can realize or omit at will---the type of being an element strictly above $n$ but below the sequence that converges down to $n$. By realizing these types according to an almost disjoint family of size continuum, we can thus find continuum many models of the theory that will be pairwise non-embeddable.

Comment: Another way to describe the same idea (but with increasing sequences). Take the rational order $\langle\mathbb{Q},<\rangle$, but with a copy of $\omega^2$ distinguished by constants. If the copy of $\omega^2$ is closed and unbounded, this is the atomic model. If the copy of $\omega^2$ is scattered and bounded, then this is the saturated model. The types to realize are the cuts below every $c_{\omega\cdot (n+1)}$ and above $c_{\omega\cdot n+k}$, (and above all the constants). We can omit or realize these independently, so there will be a continuum antichain of pairwise nonembeddable models.

Comment: Another theory: the theory of an equivalence relation with infinitely many equivalence classes, all infinite, plus infinitely many constants, one for each member of a given model. This theory admits QE, and we can get a saturated model by adding infinitely many more elements to each class, and more classes not inhabited by any constant. But again, the question of whether a given class has extra elements not named by any constant is a type that can be realized independently of the others, so we get continuum many pairwise nonembeddable models.